# To use ID Token or Access Token against an API server

Tags: authentication, oauth, jwt, access-token

I have got a React application and also a backend API server which are hosted separately. I use cognito for authentication. When the user signs in, I receive 3 tokens - id token, access token and refresh token.

I have read that id token is used for authentication while access token is used for authorisation.

I am a bit confused which token (id token or access token) should I use when making API requests to the API server.

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543948/aws-cognito-whats-the-difference-between-access-and-identity-tokens) also

Answer (score 3):

You should use the access token. It is for authorization. When you check if a user has rights to access resource it is authorization.

Authentication checks the user identity, so it gives you answer to the question - **Is this really that user?**

These terms should sink in, so read it here once more:
[Authentication versus Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556522/authentication-versus-authorization)